# require appears to only work when placed inside exported object

Tags: require

Coming across something unexpected. I have the following code:

```
var actions = require("../actions.js"); // an object of objects
module.exports = {
  rando_function: function(){
    console.log(actions); // empty object
  }
}
```

I expected to log an object of objects, but it's empty. Whereas, this works:

```
module.exports = {
  rando_function: function(){
    var actions = require("../actions.js"); // an object of objects
    console.log(actions); // an object of objects
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: require.resolve("../actions.js") gives the path that node will use to fetch the file. Can you verify that this expression returns the same value in the two cases?

Comment: I'm using Browserify and it does not have the `resolve` method (didn't know that until now). I briefly hunted for a work around but didn't find anything yet.  Also, I've been using this pattern up to this point and Browserify docs state "Relative paths are always resolved with respect to the invoking file's location", which is why I find this very odd.

Comment: Just and update, it appears it's related to a promise. I'm calling this particular code inside a promise `then` method, and receiving the error (cannot read property of undefined; i.e. when I call on a method defined in `actions.js`).